# Using regex pattern to read files from directories

Tags: python, directory, wildcard, dask

I have directories with the following names:

```
s3://bucket/elig_date=2020-06-01/
s3://bucket/elig_date=2020-06-02/
....
s3://bucket/elig_date=2020-09-30/
s3://bucket/elig_date=2020-10-01/
...
s3://bucket/elig_date=2020-12-31/
```

When I want to read all files inside all directories from 2020-06-01 to 2020-09-30, I use the following and **it works:**

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
all_data = dd.read_parquet("s3://bucket/elig_date=2020-0[6-9]-*/*")
```

But, I want to extend this upto the directory 2020-12-31, I am trying the following and it **doesn't work:**

```
all_data = dd.read_parquet("s3://bucket/elig_date=2020-0[6-9]|1[0-2]-*/*")
```

This throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-60da829cf51e> in <module>
----> 1 all_data = dd.read_parquet("s3://bucket/elig_date=2020-0[6-9]|1[0-2]-*/*") 

~/anaconda3/envs/3.8.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py in read_parquet(path, columns, filters, categories, index, storage_options, engine, gather_statistics, split_row_groups, read_from_paths, chunksize, **kwargs)
    333         index = [index]
    334 
--> 335     meta, statistics, parts, index = engine.read_metadata(
    336         fs,
    337         paths,

~/anaconda3/envs/3.8.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/arrow.py in read_metadata(cls, fs, paths, categories, index, gather_statistics, filters, split_row_groups, read_from_paths, engine, **kwargs)
    497             split_row_groups,
    498             gather_statistics,
--> 499         ) = cls._gather_metadata(
    500             paths,
    501             fs,

~/anaconda3/envs/3.8.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/arrow.py in _gather_metadata(cls, paths, fs, split_row_groups, gather_statistics, filters, index, read_from_paths, dataset_kwargs)
   1647 
   1648         # Step 1: Create a ParquetDataset object
-> 1649         dataset, base, fns = _get_dataset_object(paths, fs, filters, dataset_kwargs)
   1650         if fns == [None]:
   1651             # This is a single file. No danger in gathering statistics

~/anaconda3/envs/3.8.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/arrow.py in _get_dataset_object(paths, fs, filters, dataset_kwargs)
   1600         if proxy_metadata:
   1601             dataset.metadata = proxy_metadata
-> 1602     elif fs.isdir(paths[0]):
   1603         # This is a directory.  We can let pyarrow do its thing.
   1604         # Note: In the future, it may be best to avoid listing the

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Are you sure it accepts a regex?

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Yes, it definitely does! One of my colleagues doesn't have a problem with the `elig_date=2020-0[6-9]|1[0-2]-*/*`, it's just me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only tested it on regExr because I do not have your files.
But this worked on there:

```
s3://bucket/elig_date=2020-(0[6-9])|(1[0-2])-*/*
```

Same as you had, just with brackets

Comment: I still get the same `IndexError: list index out of range`!

Comment: Can you try the following? s3://bucket/elig_date=2020-((0[6-9])|(1[0-2]))*

Comment: I will go ahead and accept your answer as it works with regex.. there should be some problem with my kernel/packages I guess..